# .htaccess Rewrite Issue (Change of folder and filename)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to redirect:

```
site.org/us/
site.org/us/alaska/
site.org/us/south-carolina/
```

to

```
site.org/by-state/
site.org/by-state/alaska.html
site.org/by-state/south-carolina.html
```

My .htaccess code:

```
RewriteRule ^us/*$ by-state/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^us/(.*)/?$ by-state/$1.html [R=301,L]
```

Undesired results are as follows:

```
site.org/us/alaska/ is going to:
site.org/by-state/alaska/.html

site.org/us/south-carolina/ is going to:
site.org/by-state/south-carolina/.html
```

Please note the unnecessary trailing slash before .html.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^us/*$ by-state/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^us/(.*)$ by-state/$1.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Now when I type the trailing slash at the end of the URL eg. site.org/us/pennsylvania/

Then, the page returns 404 error. How to handle with slash and without slash at the end?

Comment: I am looking for a solution so I don't have to worry if the user opens up the URL with or without trailing slash at the end eg. site.org/us/alaska/ as well as site.org/us/alaska

Comment: just add another rule for the trailing slash 'RewriteRule ^us/(.*)/$ by-state/$1.html [R=301,L]'